# Tabs in IE7 looks different compared to IE8/9

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 tabs in my homepage. They work well in IE8/9. But in IE7 one of the tab looks different. Its height is more than other 2 tabs. How can i control them without changing the height since if i change the height here it renders bad in IE8/9. Here is the code:

```
<div id="fig-tabs">
          <strong class="tab1">AAA</strong> <a href="#" class="tab">BBB</a> <a href="#" class="tab">CCC</a>
        </div>
```

and it uses corner.js which uses this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.tab1').corner("5px");
   $('.tab').corner("5px");
});
```

css related:

```
#fig-tabs { }

strong.tab1
{
    color: #CCC;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 3px 8px 7px 8px;   
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.tab
{
    color: #CCC;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 3px 10px 2px 8px;  
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.tab:hover { background-color: #CCC; }
```

Comment: If I had a dollar for everything that rendered differently in IE7, I wouldn't have to make a living fixing them.

Comment: you will need to apply ie7 css hacks

Comment: Consider using a CSS reset, this might help you getting "almost expected" results

Comment: `height` property is understood as `min-height` by IE7 and 6

Comment: you're going to have to include IE7 styles for things to appear similar in IE7 and later versions. <!--[if IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" /> <![endif]-->

Comment: Your "tabs" aren't even three of the same kind of element.  One is a phrase tag, `<strong>`, and the other two are anchor tags, `<a>`.  Surely, there are better ways, like using three of the same element properly controlled and styled with CSS.